# Codeigniter reset the function in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Not even sure the best way to describe this as a question so please feel free to change it.

I have `Function mainfunction()` in my controller that controls and loads a particular view via `$this->load->view('mypage')`

I have another function, `Function updater()` in the same controller whose only job is to run a one-line update query; it is called from a button on **mypage**. After the update query runs, I call `mainfunction()` from within `updater()`, so that after the user clicks the button, **mypage** is immediately reloaded and the user sees the result of his call to `updater()`.

This appears to work on the surface: the `updater()` function runs the update and when it's finished I see **mypage** again, having been loaded from `mainfunction()`. The problem is that the URL is still pointing to /updater, with the effect that if the user hits a page refresh, it runs the update function again. How can I make it so that once the updater() function runs, it truly redirects the user back to /mainfunction in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this:

```
function mainFunction(){
 $this->load->view("view");
}

function updater(){
 //some code...
 redirect(base_url()."controller/mainFunction","refresh");
}
```